# Guid as PK low performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm facing with this issue: i have a database with around 10K rows and a GUID as PK of the table. when i'll do some select from database the response is "slow" compared to an int auto incremental PK.

I need the pseudo-randomic key that GUID is able to guarantee to me.

So, i was wondering if with using a new BIGINT KEY as PRIMARY KEY and the guid column with an index (It's really needed the index on the GUID column?) on database my performance will be better than now.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a pseduo random key?

Comment: Because every row need to be pseudo randomic

Comment: No particular techinical or business reason then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GUID Data type is most probably one of the worst candidates for a Primary key column for two main reasons.

1. It is a random value, column values being random means SQL Server will have to insert new rows somewhere in between the existing rows, which leads to a lot of page splits and fragmented indexes.
2. It being a 16 bytes data, 4 x times bigger than Integer data type means SQL Server will be processing 4 times more data just to do the same operation if it were deal with an integer value.
3. the only good thing about GUID is , it is Unique , but is it really worth paying the price you are paying for having a GUID column? I will let you decide this :)

Stick to Integer as your primary key column,  make it Identity for auto-generated values.

Comment: So, if i use an int auto increment column as PK and if i keep the guid row i will solve this problem?

Comment: Yes make an INT (Identity) column your Primary key, and keep the GUID column if you need it (not part of primary key column) , it will help a lot.

Comment: The splits and fragmentation you mentioned in #1 are bad but main performance cost of random keys on spinning media is due to expensive seek latency.  This adds several milliseconds per request.

Comment: GUID index fragmentation is not limited to PK. Any GUID index will fragment.  OP states index is needed on GUID.  Just making a int PK is not going to fix the fragmentation problem on the GUID index.

Comment: A GUID can be handy as a secondary key for use cases such as API record identifiers (to hide direct row IDs from third parties), but using them directly in internal operations is a recipe for performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

GUID index  is most likely very fractured.  Do a defrag.

GUID index clustered or non clustered is going to fragment.

Even if you move the GUID to a non clustered index that index will still fragment.  After a number of inserts you will defrag that index.  A fill factor of 50% will slow down fragmentation.

Just do a regular defrag (rebuild or reorganize) on the GUID index.
You can leave it as the PK.

Or you can use [NEWSEQUENTIALID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) to generate ordered GUID. This index will not fragment with inserts.